# Java: Add to Guava ImmutableList if optional value is present

Tags: java, list, immutability, option-type

Looking for an ideal way to add values optionally to list.
Final list must be immutable.

Example-

```
Optional<Item> optionalItem = getOptionalItemFromSomewhereElse();

List<Item> list = ImmutableList.builder()
                      .add(item1) 
                      .add(item2)
                      .optionallyAdd(optionalItem)
                  .build();
```

Comment: Is that a Guava or Java 8 `Optional`?

Comment: @shmose:l Yes, it is.

Comment: Which one??????

Comment: I'm not sure "ideal" is meaningful here.  What are the characteristics that are important to you?

Comment: `ImmutableList` is not standard Java, please spsecify

Comment: 1. java8 Optional
2. ImmutableList is just an example. It can be something else too;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would add the optional item at the end, if it's present:

```
ImmutableList.Builder<Item> builder = ImmutableList.<Item>builder()
    .add(item1)
    .add(item2);
optionalItem.ifPresent(builder::add);
```

After that, I'd build the list:

```
ImmutableList<Item> list = builder.build();
```

Comment: Already doing this, but i want to avoid this local variable- "builder"

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Guava, here's a simple one-liner:

```
List<Item> list = Stream.concat(Stream.of(item1, item2), Streams.stream(optionalItem))
        .collect(ImmutableList.toImmutableList());
```

Note: This requires at minimum Java 8 and Guava 21.

Comment: Upvoted, although I prefer the builder local variable approach. With Java 9, `Optional` has a `stream()` method that would return either a one element stream or the empty stream, so you would only need `optionalItem.stream()` instead of Guava 21's `Streams.stream(optionalItem)`

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner It was [mentioned earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925445/java-add-to-list-if-value-is-not-null/43925630?noredirect=1#comment74884323_43925445) that OP's definition of "ideal" isn't very clear. I went with my interpretation, but yours is fine too, IMO. I think it's safe to assume OP is not using Java 9. I also suspect he's using Guava's `Optional`. My solution covers either possibility.

Comment: I'm sure your solution is absolutely correct and it's also ideal, according to OP. We can safely assume OP is not using java 9 yet :) Are you saying that `Streams.stream` is overloaded to support both Java's and Guava's `Optional`?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Yes, it is.